# Any single word synonym for "fawn over"?

Tags: synonyms

I have been looking for single word that can be used in place of "fawn over"

Comment: Do you mean as an *action* (**flatter, brown-nose**), or an *attitude* (**worship, idolise**)?

Comment: What words in a thesaurus were not the right ones?

Comment: It occurs to me - does "fawn over" only mean "suck up to" or can it mean "fuss over (for example) a sick child.."

Comment: @Joe: I don't think it would normally be "standard" to use *fawn* to mean *fuss* in such contexts, but the actual meanings might easily overlap indistinguishably if you were talking about a stereotypical retired Hollywood actress fawning/fussing over her yappy toy dog carried around in a handbag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **dote** on Sally.

> to bestow or express excessive love or fondness habitually (usually followed by on or upon):

[Dictionary.Com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dote?s=t)

Answer (score 1):

Anything from *bootlicking* to *over-complimenting*, *flattering*, *blandishing*, *worshipping*, etc. (I like the verb *to blandish*).

Answer (score 0):

There's also ***crawl.***

> **Informal:** behave obsequiously or ingratiatingly in the hope of gaining
>   someone's favour. "a reporter's job can involve crawling to
>   objectionable people"
>   **synonyms:**   grovel to, be obsequious towards,
>   ingratiate oneself with, be servile towards, be sycophantic towards,
>   kowtow to, pander to, abase oneself to, demean oneself to, bow and
>   scrape to, prostrate oneself before, toady to, truckle to, dance
>   attendance on, fawn on/over, curry favour with, cultivate, seek the
>   favour of, try to win over, try to get on the good side of, make up
>   to, play up to;
>   **informal**: suck up to, lick someone's boots, creep to, be
>   all over, fall all over, rub up the right way, keep someone sweet,
>   sweet-talk, soft-soap, butter up, twist someone's arm; brown-nose;
>   vulgar slanglick/kiss someone's arse;archaic blandish

This seems to be BrEng, it's not in Merriam-Webster